# Why does not work SELECT query in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

Insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO MATCHES ("url", "league", "home_team", "away_team", "current_time", "current_score", "penalty_not_score_team", "penalty_not_score_time", "penalty_not_score_name") 
VALUES ('https://www.myscore.com.ua/match/8nsN4E4k/#match-summary', 'АРГЕНТИНА: Кубок Аргентины - 1/16', 'Химнасия Мендоса', 'Ривер Плейт', 'Послес.п.', '1 - 2', 'home', '4''', 'Andrada B.')
```

Result:

```
Result: query completed successfully
At line 1:
INSERT INTO MATCHES ("url", "league", "home_team", "away_team", "current_time", "current_score", "penalty_not_score_team", "penalty_not_score_time", "penalty_not_score_name") 
VALUES ('https://www.myscore.com.ua/match/8nsN4E4k/#match-s...', 'АРГЕНТИНА: Кубок Аргентины - 1/16', 'Химнасия Мендоса', 'Ривер Плейт', 'Послес.п.', '1 - 2', 'home', '4''', 'Andrada B.')
```

Select:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM MATCHES 
WHERE (url="https://www.myscore.com.ua/match/8nsN4E4k/#match-summary" AND league="АРГЕНТИНА: Кубок Аргентины - 1/16" AND home_team="Химнасия Мендоса" AND away_team="Ривер Плейт" AND current_time="Послес.п." AND current_score="1 - 2" AND penalty_not_score_team="home" AND penalty_not_score_time="4'" AND penalty_not_score_name="Andrada B.")
```

Result:

```
Result: 0 rows returned in 1ms
At line 1:
SELECT * 
FROM MATCHES 
WHERE (url="https://www.myscore.com.ua/match/8nsN4E4k/#match-s..." AND league="АРГЕНТИНА: Кубок Аргентины - 1/16" AND home_team="Химнасия Мендоса" AND away_team="Ривер Плейт" AND current_time="Послес.п." AND current_score="1 - 2" AND penalty_not_score_team="home" AND penalty_not_score_time="4'" AND penalty_not_score_name="Andrada B.")
```

The record in the database is 100%, I watch it with DB Browser for SQLite3
I tried different syntaxes - to no avail.
Short queries work, but I need to sample all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enquote `current_time` otherwise it is treated as function call `SELECT current_time`:

```
AND current_time="Послес.п."
=>
AND "current_time"='Послес.п.'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9bde0ea44d720e18b98ca1038eb4b79c)**

```
CREATE TABLE t(current_time CHAR(10));
INSERT INTO t(current_time) VALUES('aaa');
-- 1 row
SELECT * FROM t;

-- 0 rows returned
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE current_time = 'aaa';

-- 1 row returned
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE "current_time" = 'aaa';
```